# Change label colour lightning-input LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components, css, lightninginput, lightning-inputfield

Hello guys I am trying to change the label colour of a lightning-input in a Community that has a green default colour. I tried this approach:

```html
<lightning-combobox label="Item" class="labelColour" placeholder="Select an option" required </lightning-combobox>
```

css:

```css
.labelColour{
    -webkit-text-fill-color: black;
}
```

But the problem is that the required message is also in black and I need it in red.

Currently it looks like this:

[image]

Could anybody help me? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To change the label color of the combobox use the [styling hook](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/platforms/lightning/styling-hooks/#site-main-content) `--lwc-colorTextLabel` as below.

```
.labelColour{
    --lwc-colorTextLabel: brown;
}
```

Comment: Do you know where to find this attributes? I am trying to apply also for the placeholder color

Comment: Use `--lwc-colorTextPlaceholder` to change the placeholder color. You can use Chrome Developer Tools to find these attributes.

Comment: it is defined in slds documentation, also you can find in by inspecting the html in dev console